# Number and its logarithm as compile constants without manually changing both?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

I have a constant `WIDTH` which is always a power of 2, e.g. `#define WIDTH 1024`.

I have an associated `#define WIDTH_BINARY_LOG 10` which I **must** change every time that I modify `WIDTH`, to be the binary logarithm of `WIDTH`. This is undesirable as sometimes I forget to do so, and things consequently go haywire. Unfortunately `pow()` is also not available in macros.

Usage is

`*z = zx >> WIDTH_BINARY_LOG`.

My plan to fix this, given that the maximum possible value of `WIDTH_BINARY_LOG` is `16`, was the following usage:

`*z = zx >> BINARY_LOG(WIDTH)`

with the following defines:

```
#define BINARY_LOG_1        0
#define BINARY_LOG_2        1
#define BINARY_LOG_4        2
#define BINARY_LOG_8        3
#define BINARY_LOG_16       4
#define BINARY_LOG_32       5
#define BINARY_LOG_64       6
#define BINARY_LOG_128      7
#define BINARY_LOG_256      8
#define BINARY_LOG_512      9
#define BINARY_LOG_1024     10
#define BINARY_LOG_2048     11
#define BINARY_LOG_4096     12
#define BINARY_LOG_8192     13
#define BINARY_LOG_16384    14
#define BINARY_LOG_32768    15
#define BINARY_LOG_65536    16

#define BINARY_LOG(n)       BINARY_LOG_##n
```

or

```
#define BINARY_LOG(n)       BINARY_LOG_#n
```

However, gcc complains bitterly in each case. What am I doing wrong? How would others tackle this problem, assuming the way above is completely unworthy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It **can** be done with macros. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5256500/4722212) in my code:

```
#define WIDTH 2048

#define BINARY_LOG_1        0
#define BINARY_LOG_2        1
#define BINARY_LOG_4        2
#define BINARY_LOG_8        3
#define BINARY_LOG_16       4
#define BINARY_LOG_32       5
#define BINARY_LOG_64       6
#define BINARY_LOG_128      7
#define BINARY_LOG_256      8
#define BINARY_LOG_512      9
#define BINARY_LOG_1024     10
#define BINARY_LOG_2048     11
#define BINARY_LOG_4096     12
#define BINARY_LOG_8192     13
#define BINARY_LOG_16384    14
#define BINARY_LOG_32768    15
#define BINARY_LOG_65536    16

#define PPCAT_NX(A, B) A ## B
#define BINARY_LOG(B) PPCAT_NX(BINARY_LOG_, B)

BINARY_LOG(WIDTH)
```

Output of `gcc -E test.c` (only macro substitution phase):

```
>gcc -E test.c
# 1 "test.c"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "test.c"
# 24 "test.c"
11
```

Comment: Yes. You are right. I had seen this (the indirection) in another answer at some stage, and am in fact using such in one of my collections libraries. Cheers :)

Answer (score -2):

Since there are already working answers available, I want to point to some different solution:

Using constexpr (C++11) that can be evaluated at compile-time to calculate WIDTH from a given exponent. This looks much nicer than the use of macros IMHO: (see Casey's answer in [c++11 fast constexpr integer powers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719674/c11-fast-constexpr-integer-powers))

```
#include <cstdint>

constexpr int64_t ipow(int64_t base, int exp, int64_t result = 1) {
  return exp < 1 ? result : ipow(base*base, exp/2, (exp % 2) ? result*base : result);
}

int64_t foo(int64_t base, int exp) {
  return ipow(base, exp);
}
```

Comment: Am I using C++? Can someone please stop you C++ users from posting on C questions? Thanks!