# `#define` a very large number in c++ source code

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, compile-time

Well, the question is not as silly as it sound.

I am using C++11 `<array>` and want to declare an array like this:

```
array<int, MAX_ARR_SIZE> myArr;
```

The `MAX_ARR_SIZE` is to be defined in a header file and could be very large i.e. 10^13. Currently I am typing it like a pre-school kid

```
 #define MAX_ARR_SIZE 1000000000000000
```

I can live with it if there is no alternative. I can't use `pow(10, 13)` here since it can not be evaluated at compile time; array initialization will fail. I am not aware of any shorthand to type this.

Comment: Well you could do `const size_t max_array_size = 10e15;`, but an array that size is likely too large for the stack. Having a `MAX_ARR_SIZE` indicates that you have some kind of dynamic sizing; is there a reason you aren't using `std::vector`?

Comment: @TartanLlama or `constexpr size_t max_array_size = 10e15;`

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)…

Comment: @TartanLlama Doing benchmarking of a custom random number generator ;-) . Have already done it with vector; thought give it a try with array (plan is to have a concurrent version for GPU and openMPI)

Comment: @Garf365 I assumed that `a e b` expression would be of type `float` or `double`?  Got this impression from this page http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types ; they did not use this either.

Comment: @Dilawar no, it's type `size_t` (unsigned interger type)

Comment: @Garf365 No, it's a [`double`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/230e6febd866cab1) which we convert to an integral type.

Comment: @TartanLlama right, apologize, I take a shortcut ;)

Comment: note: this will fail if your system doesn't have 4000 (or 8000) terabytes of ram free ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a `constexpr` function:

```
constexpr size_t MAX_ARR_SIZE()
{
    return pow(10, 15); 
}
```

That way you can do even more complex calculations in compile time.

Then use it as `array<int, MAX_ARR_SIZE()> myArr;` it will be evaluated in compile time.

Also like it was already mentioned, you probably won't be able to allocate that size on the stack.

**EDIT**:

I have a **fault** here, since pow itself is not constexpr you can't use it, but it's solvable, for example use ipow as discussed here: [c++11 fast constexpr integer powers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719674/c11-fast-constexpr-integer-powers)

here is the function quote:

> ```
> constexpr int64_t ipow(int64_t base, int exp, int64_t result = 1) {
>   return exp < 1 ? result : ipow(base*base, exp/2, (exp % 2) ? result*base : result);
> }
> ```

simply change `MAX_ARR_SIZE()` to:

```
constexpr size_t MAX_ARR_SIZE()
{
    return ipow(10, 15); 
}
```

Comment: This is great. It solves this problem and a great general tip.

Comment: @dilawar if it solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer ;)

Answer (score 9):

Using **#define** for constants is more a way of C than C++.

You can define your constant in this way:

```
const size_t MAX_ARR_SIZE(1e15);
```

Comment: Or `constexpr` for C++11 (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346879/const-vs-constexpr-on-variables)

Answer (score 7):

In this case, using a `const size_t` instead of `#define` is preferred.

---

I'd like to add that, since C++14, when writing integer literals, you could add the optional single quotes as separator.

```
1'000'000'000'000'000
```

This looks more clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define MAX_ARRAY_SIZE (1000ull * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 * 1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

`#define MAX_ARR_SIZE 1e15`

`1e15` is very huge and probably would not be allocated.

Comment: Ten times too big.

Comment: @gnasher yes i fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

You actually can evaluate pow(10, 15) and similar expressions at compile time in C++11 if you use a const instead of #define. Just make sure you pick a large enough primitive.